# add multiple images from openfiledilog to imagelist and display them in the listview

Tags: c#

hello friends i am new to c# i am in a project and i want help

i want to add multiple images from openfiledilog to imagelist and display them in the listview.

its adding the images but showing the same picture 
 and here goes my code.. please help me

```
     int b = 0;![enter image description here][1]
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        for (int z = 1; z <= ofd.FileNames.Length ; z++)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
            string a = b.ToString();
            imageList1.Images.Add(a, img);
            var listViewItem = listView1.Items.Add("1");
            listViewItem.ImageKey = a;
            b++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `FileNames` array instead of using the `FileName` property.

```
    int b = 0;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        for (int z = 0; z < ofd.FileNames.Length ; z++)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileNames[z]);
            string a = b.ToString();
            imageList1.Images.Add(a, img);
            var listViewItem = listView1.Items.Add("1");
            listViewItem.ImageKey = a;
            b++;
        }
    }
```

or

```
int b = 0;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    ofd.ShowDialog();
    foreach (string fileName in ofd.FileNames)
    {
        Image img = Image.FromFile(fileName);
        string a = b.ToString();
        imageList1.Images.Add(a, img);
        var listViewItem = listView1.Items.Add("1");
        listViewItem.ImageKey = a;
        b++;
    }
}
```